# XML Parsing Python with xmltodict

Tags: python, xml, parsing, xmltodict

I need to extract information from various xml files within a directory. They all have the same structure but might have different amounts of values stored in pair " " /pair. I'm using xmltodict to access the different pair "values" /pair and store them in a dict. 
The xml unfortunately looks somethin like this:

```
<license xmlns:="http://www.example.com">
    <application name="TEST">
        <operation>
            <condition implication="stop" name="module">
                <arguments>
                    <pair key="version">1</pair>
                </arguments>
            </condition>
            <condition implication="stop" name="allowed">
                <arguments>
                    <pair key="commandName">value1</pair>
                    <pair key="commandName">value2</pair>
                    <pair key="commandName">value3</pair>
                    <pair key="commandName">value4</pair>
                </arguments>
            </condition>
        </operation>
     </application>
</applications>
```

This is definitely not the best solution but I'm a total beginner and need to make this work. My code looks something like this

```
if application['@name'] == "Test":
   for pair in application['operation']['condition'][1]['arguments']:
       if pair["@key"]["#text"] == 'value1':
          value1 = 'available'
       if pair["@key"]["#text"] == 'value2':
          value2 = 'available'
....
Test_dict = {'value1': value1, 'value2': value2....}
```

And this is my output:

```
if pair["@key"]["#text"] == 'value1':

TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

How can I get this to work?

---

EDIT:

Me again, still trying to work this one out.

Jonathans Solution works for all scenarios, except for the one where I have one pair value only. for example:

```
<license xmlns:="http://www.example.com">
    <application name="TEST">
        <operation>
            <condition implication="stop" name="module">
                <arguments>
                    <pair key="version">1</pair>
                </arguments>
            </condition>
            <condition implication="stop" name="allowed">
                <arguments>
                    <pair key="commandName">value1</pair>
                </arguments>
            </condition>
        </operation>
     </application>
</license>
```

I still get the same error message.

```
if pair["#text"] == 'value2': TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

As long as there is more than one pair value this approach works perfectly fine. Any approach on how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

You're getting that error because you treat the string value inside `pair["@key"]` like a dict.

Try using `if pair["#text"] == 'value1':` and it should work.

The full code that works for me:

```
import xmltodict

xml = """
    <application name="TEST">
        <operation>
            <condition implication="stop" name="module">
                <arguments>
                    <pair key="version">1</pair>
                </arguments>
            </condition>
            <condition implication="stop" name="allowed">
                <arguments>
                    <pair key="commandName">value1</pair>
                    <pair key="commandName">value2</pair>
                    <pair key="commandName">value3</pair>
                    <pair key="commandName">value4</pair>
                </arguments>
            </condition>
        </operation>
     </application>
"""

d = xmltodict.parse(xml)

if d['application']['@name'] == "TEST":
    for pair in d['application']['operation']['condition'][1]['arguments']['pair']:
        if pair["#text"] == 'value1':
            value1 = 'available'
        if pair["#text"] == 'value2':
            value2 = 'available'

print(value1, value2)
```

Comment: I updated the main question. Any chance you could look over it again?